# view to perform select from multiple tables in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Sample view:

```
create or replace view test_sel as
    select * 
    from xyz 
    where processdte in (select distinct PROCESS_DTE 
                         from ABC 
                         where STATUS = 'Y'
                        );
```

Requirement:

Should perform the select of table if the status is yes , if not should display message stating please wait or something.

Kindly guide on how to achieve the same

Comment: I don't understand.  Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe:

```
create or replace view test_sel as
    select xyz.* ,
           case abc.STATUS 
           when 'Y' then ''
           else 'Please wait'
            end as Message
    from xyz join (select PROCESS_DTE, MAX(STATUS) as STATUS /* guessing Status Y/N/null*/
                     from ABC 
                    group by PROCESS_DTE) abc
       on xyz.processdte = abc.PROCESS_DTE;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sorry to post it again but not able to comment because of low experience.

Just Changed abc.processdte to abc.PROCESS_DTE in last line.

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW test_sel AS   SELECT xyz.* ,
    CASE abc.STATUS
      WHEN 'Y'
      THEN ''
      ELSE 'Please wait'
    END AS MESSAGE   FROM xyz   JOIN
    (SELECT PROCESS_DTE,
      MAX(STATUS) AS STATUS
      /* guessing Status Y/N/null*/
    FROM ABC
    GROUP BY PROCESS_DTE
    ) abc   ON xyz.processdte = abc.PROCESS_DTE;
```